# Can the scope resolution operator be used in the definition of a member function when the member function is defined outside of its class definition?

Tags: c++, class, member-functions, scope-resolution

Can the scope resolution operator be used in the definition of a member function when the member function is defined outside of its class definition? Like this:

```
class Myclass{
    private:
    void foo();
    public:
    void foo2();
};

void Myclass::foo()
    {
    // do stuff. . . 
    }
```

My teacher gave us notes that demonstrate the use of the scope resolution operator only for member functions that are public. Can anyone clear this up?

Comment: Well, it compiles, doesn’t that answer your question?

Comment: Umm, not only is it possible, it's mandatory for member functions. So...

Comment: @Darklighter compilers compile a lot of things that don't follow the standard indeed.

Comment: @Darklighter: In C and C++, "it compiles" must never be used as a test of validness. The standards give compilers a lot of leeway and liberty when it comes to compiling invalid statements.